# Creating a thread-safe temporary file name

Tags: ruby, thread-safety, filenames, temp

When using `Tempfile` Ruby is creating a file with a thread-safe and inter-process-safe name. I only need a file name in that way.

I was wondering if there is a more straight forward approach way than:

```
t = Tempfile.new(['fleischwurst', '.png'])
temp_path = t.path
t.close
t.unlink
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### Dir::Tmpname.create

You could use `Dir::Tmpname.create`. It figures out what temporary directory to use (unless you pass it a directory). It's a little ugly to use given that it expects a block:

```
require 'tmpdir'
# => true
Dir::Tmpname.create(['prefix-', '.ext']) {}
# => "/tmp/prefix-20190827-1-87n9iu.ext"
Dir::Tmpname.create(['prefix-', '.ext'], '/my/custom/directory') {}
# => "/my/custom/directory/prefix-20190827-1-11x2u0h.ext"
```

The block is there for code to test if the file exists and raise an `Errno::EEXIST` so that a new name can be generated with incrementing value appended on the end.

### The Rails Solution

The solution implemented by [Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31462/files) is short and similar to the solution originally implemented in Ruby:

```
require 'tmpdir'
# => true
File.join(Dir.tmpdir, "YOUR_PREFIX-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}-#{$$}-#{rand(0x100000000).to_s(36)}-YOUR_SUFFIX")
=> "/tmp/YOUR_PREFIX-20190827-1-wyouwg-YOUR_SUFFIX"
File.join(Dir.tmpdir, "YOUR_PREFIX-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}-#{$$}-#{rand(0x100000000).to_s(36)}-YOUR_SUFFIX")
=> "/tmp/YOUR_PREFIX-20190827-1-140far-YOUR_SUFFIX"
```

### Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname (Ruby 2.5.0 and earlier)

> Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname was removed in Ruby 2.5.0. Prior to Ruby 2.4.4 it could accept a directory path as a prefix, but as of Ruby 2.4.4, directory separators are removed.

Digging in `tempfile.rb` you'll notice that `Tempfile` includes `Dir::Tmpname`. Inside you'll find [`make_tmpname`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/tmpdir.rb#108) which does what you ask for.

```
require 'tmpdir'
# => true
File.join(Dir.tmpdir, Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname("prefix-", nil))
# => "/tmp/prefix-20190827-1-dfhvld"
File.join(Dir.tmpdir, Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname(["prefix-", ".ext"], nil))
# => "/tmp/prefix-20190827-1-19zjck1.ext"
File.join(Dir.tmpdir, Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname(["prefix-", ".ext"], "suffix"))
# => "/tmp/prefix-20190827-1-f5ipo7-suffix.ext"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Can be used with an array argument as well to preserve the file name extension: `Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname(['a', '.png'], nil)`

Comment: @iltempo, you're welcome. I've added your example to the answer.

Comment: This is great but nobody has mentioned that you need to `require 'tmpdir'` for this to work.

Comment: `Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname` was [removed in Ruby 2.5](https://medium.com/@maciejmensfeld/ruby-2-5-0-upgrade-remarks-100d7c0dd73d)

Comment: As of Ruby 2.4.4 this functionality no longer works, as make_tmpname doesn't take a directory anymore, just a filename prefix (directory separator characters are removed)

Comment: is it just me, or is there no ruby docs for the built-in `Dir::Tmpname.create`? I can't find any!

Comment: Tempfile.new already uses Dir::Tmpname.create under the hood, so I'm not sure how explicitly using Dir::Tmpname.create gains anything different. The Ruby docs suggest using a mutex to protect the tempfile from multiple threads. Also, @jrochkind here is the source code for that method https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2a02b61fae2c5dcfaf123f43c08c7c7949c1790c/lib/tmpdir.rb#L128

Comment: @chemturion Sometimes you need a temporary file name without the file having already been created.  That's why I use this construct.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname` was [removed in Ruby 2.5.0](https://medium.com/@maciejmensfeld/ruby-2-5-0-upgrade-remarks-100d7c0dd73d), this one falls back to using `SecureRandom`:

```
require "tmpdir"

def generate_temp_filename(ext=".png")
  filename = begin
    Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname(["x", ext], nil)
  rescue NoMethodError
    require "securerandom"
    "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}#{ext}"
  end
  File.join(Dir.tmpdir, filename)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need the filename, what about using the [SecureRandom](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) for that:

```
require 'securerandom'

filename =  "#{SecureRandom.hex(6)}.png" #=> "0f04dd94addf.png"
```

You can also use `SecureRandom.alphanumeric`

Answer (score -2):

I found the Dir:Tmpname solution did not work for me.  When evaluating this:

```
Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname "/tmp/blob", nil
```

Under MRI Ruby 1.9.3p194 I get:

```
uninitialized constant Dir::Tmpname (NameError)
```

Under JRuby 1.7.5 (1.9.3p393) I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Dir::Tmpname
```

You might try something like this:

```
def temp_name(file_name='', ext='', dir=nil)
    id   = Thread.current.hash * Time.now.to_i % 2**32
    name = "%s%d.%s" % [file_name, id, ext]
    dir ? File.join(dir, name) : name
end
```

Comment: Before you used Dir::Tempname id you require 'tempfile'

require 'tempfile' Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname "/tmp/blob", nil

If you haven't loaded 'Tempfile' then you won't be able to use it's extensions to Dir